# Please explain the conclusion of this code

Tags: python, filesystems

can you tell me what exactly the variable "count" counts ?

```
    count = 0
    for (r,d,f) in 
        os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        count += 1
    print("a =", count)

    #a = 124
```

Comment: please read document about `os.walk` from official python page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `help(os.walk)` will tell you:

> Directory tree generator.
>
> For each directory in the directory tree rooted at top (including top itself, but excluding '.' and '..'), yields a 3-tuple `dirpath, dirnames, filenames`

So, `count` counts folders (also nested ones) in (and including) the current working directory.

Comment: thank you but '.' isnt the current one ?because the help(os.walk) says that '.' is excuded

Comment: That is a bit confusing, but it is included with its absolute path (as returned by `os.getcwd`, if you did `os.walk(".")` explicitly, `"."` would be included as well). I guess the statement is there, because `ls -la` in Linux systems lists "." and ".." as directories.